# React: Having trouble rendering nested json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, key

I have a nested json running in my local server and I'm trying to practice react by being able to output this nested data. For this one, I'm trying to just show the day and output available time-slots during the day. I'm at the stage of trying to reach outputting each "slot" and will be putting more features using buttons/toggles.

With the following codes, I can only get up to what I think is fetching the "days"(mon,tues...). Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think they're only parsed as strings instead of maintaining as objects or arrays so I don't notice that I can fetch the "slots". The other evidence is that when I try to map a "day", it's mapping the string.

I think my issue is that I haven't understood and lose track of props when it's being passed down the component tree. The tutorials and guides explain the general sense of mapping, but I either lost a specific detail to maintain props or I'm doing something wrong with mapping, in general.

Also, as you can probably tell, this is my first code-related post on the internet. I'd like to also ask for your tip of asking or giving helpful feeds with regards to coding (or like pet-peeves). I'd like to be more involved with these resources to test/practice my knowledge with other people's problems.

And of course, nit-pick any preferable react syntax. I'm only a week old in this and trying to absorb as much information about react as I can.

**json**

```
const advisor = [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: { first: "John", last: "Doe" },
      email: "jdoe@harvard.edu",
      availability: {
        monday: {
          slot: { start: 1400, end: 1410, available: true, student: null },
          slot: { start: 1415, end: 1425, available: true, student: null },
          slot: { start: 1430, end: 1440, available: false, student: null },
          slot: { start: 1445, end: 1455, availabie: true, student: null }
        },
        tuesday: {},
        wednesday: {},
        thurday: {
          // slot1: { start: 1400, end: 1410, available: true, student: null },
          // slot2: { start: 1415, end: 1425, available: true, student: null },
          // slot3: { start: 1430, end: 1440, available: true, student: null },
          // slot4: { start: 1445, end: 1455, availabie: true, student: null }
        },
        friday: {}
      }
    }
  ];
```

**App**

```
import React from "react";
import Advisors from "./components/advisors/advisors.jsx";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Advisors />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Advisors**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Availability from "./availability/availability.jsx";

class Advisors extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      advisors: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchData();
  };

  fetchData = () => {
    fetch("/api/advisors")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(
        advisors => this.setState({ advisors })
      )
      .catch(error => console.log("Parse Failed", error));
  };

  render() {
    const { advisors } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {advisors.map(advisor => {

          return (
            <div key={advisor.id}>
              <h2>
                {advisor.name.first} {advisor.name.last}
              </h2>
              <h6>{advisor.email}</h6>
              {Object.keys(advisor.availability).map((day, key) => (
                //keys = {mon, tues, wed, thu, fri}
                <Availability key={key} day={day} />
              ))}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Advisors;
```

**Availability**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Availability extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { day } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>{day}</h4>
        <ul>
          {Object.keys(day).map((x, i) => {
            return <li key={i}>{x.start}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Availability;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass both the keys and values of `availability` into your child `< Availability />` component.

First and foremost, you should ensure the keys within your `availability` object from your HTTP request are unique. Currently, all of them have the same key, `slot`. You can consider changing the names to `slot1`, `slot2`, etc.

```
const advisor = [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: { first: "John", last: "Doe" },
      email: "jdoe@harvard.edu",
      availability: {
        monday: {
          slot1: { start: 1400, end: 1410, available: true, student: null },
          slot2: { start: 1415, end: 1425, available: true, student: null },
          slot3: { start: 1430, end: 1440, available: false, student: null },
          slot4: { start: 1445, end: 1455, availabie: true, student: null }
        },
        // others
      }
    }
  ];
```

On your parent `Advisors` component, this is what you need to change. As you can see, you will need to pass in the entire `availability` object into your child component, such that the data is available for rendering.

```
{Object.keys(advisor.availability).map((day, key) => (
  <Availability key={key} day={day} availability={advisor.availability[day]}/>
))}
```

And on your child `Availability` component,

you will need to map and render the availability start times that is passed into it as the props.

```
<ul>
  {Object.keys(availability).map((x, i) => {
    return <li key={i}>{availability[x].start}</li>;
  })}
</ul>
```

I have created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-browser-jj84m) over here.

Comment: Wow the syntax makes total sense when it looks like this. I forgot the possibility of passing availability in the component. I thought it was illegal to pass advisor.availability when I use it from Object.keys, but that's obviously the thing I've been trying to pass the entire time!

Is there also a term for 'day=' 'availability='? props? children?

Comment: Also, if you know that the last json layer is (start,end,available,student), would you prefer making another new component that branches Availability? or render the children all in Availability?

Comment: They are called props! You may read more about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I think it is fine to render the it in Availability :) The way you are doing it is already quite good

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the way you're passing props. Notice this line

```js
Object.keys(advisor.availability).map((day, key) => (
   //keys = {mon, tues, wed, thu, fri}
   <Availability key={key} day={day} />
))
```

`Object.keys(advisor.availability)` returns the array `[mon, tues, wed, thu, fri]`. Now, in `arr.map((day,key)=>{})`, day takes the values `mon,tues,wed,etc.` one by one and it's a string which you're passing on as props to `<Availability/>`

In order to pass the value object, it should be

```js
Object.keys(advisor.availability).map((day, key) => (
   <Availability key={key} day={advisor.availability[day]} />
))
```

Now, another issue is in your `advisor` object. Notice `monday` key in your object. It's having the same key `slot` multiple times, which isn't allowed in a JS object so JS will replace it with the last slot and you end up having just 1 slot.

```js
monday: {
  slot: { start: 1400, end: 1410, available: true, student: null },
  slot: { start: 1415, end: 1425, available: true, student: null },
  slot: { start: 1430, end: 1440, available: false, student: null },
  slot: { start: 1445, end: 1455, availabie: true, student: null }
}
```

You can fix it in two ways(maybe more).

1. Change keys to slot1, slot2, etc. Ex.,

```js
monday: {
  slot1: { start: 1400, end: 1410, available: true, student: null },
  slot2: { start: 1415, end: 1425, available: true, student: null },
  slot3: { start: 1430, end: 1440, available: false, student: null },
  slot4: { start: 1445, end: 1455, availabie: true, student: null }
}
```

and in `Availability.js`, replace this code

```js
{Object.keys(day).map((x, i) => {
  return <li key={i}>{x.start}</li>;
})}
```

with this

```js
{Object.keys(day).map((x, i) => {
  return <li key={i}>{day[x].start}</li>;
})}
```

2. Another way is to defined it as array. Ex.

```js
monday: [
  { start: 1400, end: 1410, available: true, student: null },
  { start: 1415, end: 1425, available: true, student: null },
  { start: 1430, end: 1440, available: false, student: null },
  { start: 1445, end: 1455, availabie: true, student: null }
]
```

and in `Availability.js`, replace this code

```js
{Object.keys(day).map((x, i) => {
  return <li key={i}>{x.start}</li>;
})}
```

with this

```js
{day.map((x, i) => {
  return <li key={i}>{x.start}</li>;
})}
```

Comment: With updating the way I passed props, I tried your first solution and I got an error from trying to pass [x].start, saying it's an object with keys and needs to be rendered as an array. I figure it's because x is the next layer of nested json with (start,end,available,student) and I'd have to map day[x]?

The second solution does look very clean and gets rid of the slot redundancy. This was a dilemma I was having because I'm planning to make the number of slots be a variable amount so I may be likely to use this down this project.

Comment: Also, if you know that the last json layer is (start,end,available,student), would you prefer making another new component that branches Availability? or render the children all in Availability?